# Symfony connect to oracle oci8

Tags: oracle, symfony, connect, oci8

I'm on Symfony and I can't connect to a Oracle database, but I don't know why. Maybe you can help me a little.

Here my doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            # configure these for your database server
            url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
        test:
            # configure these for your database server
            url: '%env(DATABASE_TEST_URL)%'
            driver: 'oci8'
            server_version: ~
            charset: utf8mb4


orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
        test:
            connection: test
            mappings:
                test:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Test'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Test'
                    alias: Test
```

My .env file with 2 database:

```
   DATABASE_URL=mysql://xxx:xxx@mysql:3306/pivot
   DATABASE_TEST_URL=//user:owd@host:port/dbname
```

And here my controller

```
public function xxx() {
 $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('test');
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM xxx.O2_ADRESSE WHERE ROWNUM = 1';
        $stmt = $entityManager->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        dump($stmt->fetchAll());
}
```

I get the following error :

```
An exception occurred in driver: ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Any help on what im doing wrong?

Comment: Well, that error message is a good sign - it means you connected to the Listener, but it doesn't know of a database with a SID of "dbname". Check your connection settings against a working environment - I haven't used Symfony, but if "dbname" is a *service name* and not a SID, you might try setting `service: true` in the connection properties. See the Oracle-specific settings. https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working !
And I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the db is running?
You can check it via sqlplus, eg:

sqlplus user:password@mysql:3306/pivot

Comment: Yes, I can see the result of my sql request.
I just miss an arugment on connection:`service: true`

Answer (score 0):

Can you update DATABASE_URL and try?

to use oracle: DATABASE_URL="oci8://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:1521/db_name"

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html#oracle-db

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)